# Variable resetting in C#

Tags: c#

I have an application were I need a variable to be constantly incrementing.

Example:

```
float dataStream = test1 - test2;

test0 = dataStream;
```

But when the data stream resets, so does the test0 . How can I prevent that, so test0 keep its previous number so when dataStream gets data it adds onto test0 ? I cannot wrap my head around it

edit:
Added a screenshot of my code http://prntscr.com/7u42i1

The code is running in a function that is constantly running, so the += won't work as it's constantly incrementing (going beyond dataStream)

Edit2

dataStream streams data from an API and test0 is the variable that stores.

When the dataStream gets a new value I want it to add onto test0, but every method I've tried always goes over.

```
//firstFuelCount - data.Drivetrain.Fuel is the calculation that needs to be added onto test3
//When refueling, firstFuelCount - data.Drivetrain.Fuel decreases, so does test3

test2 = data.Drivetrain.FuelMax - data.Drivetrain.Fuel;
if (test2 < test3)
{
}
else
{
    test3 = data.Drivetrain.FuelMax - data.Drivetrain.Fuel;                    
}
```

Basically

```
float dataStream = test1 - test2;

test0 = dataStream;

dataStram = 5
test0 = 5

dataStream = 1
test0 = 6
```

etc..

This is a constant running script.

Comment: Is dataStream is a field or a property of a class ?

Comment: Screenshots of code are not the preferred approach: harder to read, we can't copy and run it ourselves, etc. You should copy/paste your code into your question (format code with four spaces in front of it for Markdown to recognize/format it as code), preferably a [short but complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you need help with. It sounds like you may have an issue with the scope of `test3` and your other variables, so focus on that.

Comment: Please explain your program flow better. You want to add `dataStream` to `test0`, but at the same time you don't want to?

Comment: I have taken a moment to format your code. I know you're @LazyCoder, but you need to take the time to properly format your code for readability when asking a question here. Code needs to be indented 4 spaces, indenting more than that for the first indention reduces readability and makes it less likely for you to receive an answer. Your question *still* needs improvement, as you did not provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need an MCVE, because some important details such as where your variables are declared has been left out the question.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. Probably aged 100 years in the process

```
            //Only for testing
            var fakeCurrFuelDrive = fakeCurrFuel;

            //Check if the engine is running before calcualting burned lites
            if (data.Drivetrain.EngineRpm >= 50)
            {
                //Ensure variable has data
                if (drivenOldFuel == 0)
                {
                    //Set variable for next check
                    drivenOldFuel = fakeCurrFuelDrive;
                }

                //Distance travelled - refueling
                if ((drivenOldFuel - fakeCurrFuelDrive) < 0)
                {
                    drivenCurrentFuel = fuel + (fakeCurrFuelDrive - drivenOldFuel);
                }

                //Check for refueling
                if ((drivenOldFuel - fakeCurrFuelDrive) > 0)
                {
                    drivenCurrentFuel = fuel + (drivenOldFuel - fakeCurrFuelDrive);
                }

                //Set variable for next check
                drivenOldFuel = fakeCurrFuelDrive;
                fuel = drivenCurrentFuel;
            }
```